# Why are there two separate FAQs on each site?

Tags: discussion

There's [Frequently Asked Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) linked from 'FAQ' at the top right of all pages.
These are about using the site.

And there's [Faq Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=faq) linked from the'FAQ' tab under Questions.
These are 'the questions [asked on the site] with the most links'.

Is there a better way of labelling these?

Comment: Maybe. We could reserve `Frequently Asked Questions` for the second case (most links) and call the first case (top right) `Meta-FAQ`. Then we can proceed to call the `Meta-FAQ` on meta `Meta-Meta-FAQ` (or possibly `Hypertime-FAQ`).

Answer (score 12):

I've always favored something like `user guide`  or `help` or `intro` for the site faq link, and *Welcome to [Site Name]* or *How [Site Name] Works* for the page title.

FAQ just seems odd to me, but I'm told it is universally understood to be the place you go when you want to find out about a new site.

Comment: Seems odd to me too, with 'FAQs' being put up when nobody asked the questions in the first place - nowadays it is more in anticipation of what common questions users might have, acronym has become something of a misnomer imho.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "help" is universally understood too

Comment: @Robert, the site FAQ follows the same Q/A format as the rest of the site, so I guess it predates the FAQ tab and used what seemed to be a good label back then. `help` is indeed nice, I was about to suggest `howto` but, like `intro`, it's not as meaningful IMHO. How about `usage`?

Comment: @Frédéric: `usage` is a programmer term, not widely understood across the SE network.

Comment: @Robert, good point. I don't think I can devise anything better than `help`, then :)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fought over elsewhere, IIRC, and *the power that be's* came out pretty heavily *against* anything other than faq (i.e. 'help', as Robert is proposing).

I think 'about' would be a pretty good link text for the 'pseudo-faq'.

*I know (or rather, I just noticed) that there is already an 'about' link in the footer. I'm not sure what the semantic difference is with the current faq, but it seems to me that the two could quite easily be merged.*